# HQL query to get data from multiple tables

Tags: hibernate, mapping, hql, parent-child

I have 2 tables - A and B. And each has a corresponding hbm.xml and pojo.

`Class A{

  String aId;

  String col;

}

Class B{

  String bId;

  String aId;//as reference to class A

  A aObj;

}

B.hbm.xml contains the following entry to map A to B:

<many-to-one name="aId" column="AID" not-null="true" class="com.pojo.A" unique="true"/>`


My requirement is that, whenever an object of B is created, it should push data into table A as well. Similarly when I read from B, it should give me data from A as well based on **aId** match. It is a one-one mapping. I want to pass the **aId** value as input to the query. And get the data from both the tables corresponding to that matched row.
Can some one tell me how to use HQL queries to achieve this? And is the structure that I have now is correct for my requirement?

Answer (score 1):

You classes are incorrect. The B class should have a field of type A, but not have an `aId` field.

Read the Hibernate documentation on [unidirectional OneToOne associations](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#assoc-unidirectional-121), since this is what you have.

Your requirements indicate that you should [cascade](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#objectstate-transitive) all operations from B to A, and that this association should be eagerly fetched (with `<many-to-one lazy="false"...>`).

Comment: After I made these changes, when I try to run the code, I get an exception running the following HQL:
select bAlias, bAlias.aObj from B bAlias where bAlias.aObj.aId=? and bAlias.aObj.col=? 
 Error I get is:Invalid Object Name B (where B is the table name)